# Using a while with no body to wait

Tags: java, swing

I have a Jtextfield and a Jbutton, pressing the Jbutton will put the value in an int or string, and changes `gettingentry` to 1. What I want is to wait for something to get entered, so I wait for `gettingentry` to get to 1. But when i have a while with no body (what i want), it never leaves the while. I've tried to put `System.out.println(gettingentry + " ; " + entry);` in the while to see what were the values, maybe something was preventing `gettingentry` to get to 1, but putting this makes everything work. The issue is that I don't get why, when i had the empty while, it did not work, I don't need the values to be always shown in the console in the end, but it helps my program work.

Here is how my Jbutton works:

```
select.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String getValue = textfield.getText();
        try {
            entry = Integer.parseInt(getValue);
            String sendback = "entry : " + entry;
            logger.log(Level.INFO, sendback);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            entrystr = getValue;
            logger.log(Level.INFO, entrystr);
        }
        textfield.setText("");
        gettingentry=1;
    }
});
```

And here is my while:

```
gettingentry=0;
while (gettingentry==0); {
    //System.out.println(gettingentry + " ; " + entry);
}
int viewid = entry;
gettingentry = 0;
```

Here is the whole .java, where everything works, but i would like to get rid of the `System.out.println(gettingentry + " ; " + entry);` everytime i wait for a value. Btw sorry if it's not well writen, I'm still a begginer:

```
package net.jpatest;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AlbumManager {
    static EntityManagerFactory factory;
    static EntityManager entityManager;
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AlbumManager.class.getName());
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int etat;
    static int entry = 0;
    static JFrame f = new JFrame("Music");
    static String entrystr;
    static JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(10, 30);
    static int gettingentry = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        begin();

        int run = 1;
        int etatmenu = 1;
        while (run == 1) {
            if (etatmenu == 1) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "1: View album\n2: Create album\n3: Delete album\n4: Update album\n5: Exit");
                textarea.setText("1: View album\n2: Create album\n3: Delete album\n4: Update album\n5: Exit");
                etatmenu = 0;
            }
            etat = entry;

            // etat = scanner.nextInt();
            // scanner.nextLine();
            switch (etat) {
            case 1:
                gettingentry = 0;
                viewalbum();
                etatmenu = 1;
                etat = 0;
                entry = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                createalbum();
                update();
                etatmenu = 1;
                etat = 0;
                entry = 0;
                break;
            case 3:
                deletealbum();
                update();
                etatmenu = 1;
                etat = 0;
                entry = 0;
                break;
            case 4:
                updatealbum();
                update();
                etatmenu = 1;
                etat = 0;
                entry = 0;
                break;
            case 5:
                run = 0;
                etatmenu = 1;
                etat = 0;
                entry = 0;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }

        end();
    }

    private static void update() {
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    }

    private static void end() {
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
        factory.close();
        scanner.close();
        f.dispose();
    }

    private static void begin() {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AlbumUnit");
        entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

        f.setSize(400, 250);
        f.setLocation(300, 200);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // the panel is not visible in output
        JButton select = new JButton("OK");
        JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");
        JRootPane rootPane = f.getRootPane();
        rootPane.setDefaultButton(select);
        JTextField textfield = new JTextField(20);
        panel.add(textarea);
        panel.add(textfield);
        panel.add(select);
        panel.add(quit);

        f.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);

        quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.exit(0);

            }
        });

        select.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                String getValue = textfield.getText();
                try {
                    entry = Integer.parseInt(getValue);
                    String sendback = "entry : " + entry;
                    logger.log(Level.INFO, sendback);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    entrystr = getValue;
                    logger.log(Level.INFO, entrystr);
                }
                textfield.setText("");
                gettingentry = 1;
            }
        });

        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void createalbum() {
        Album newalbum = new Album();
        int newid = (int) getnbofalbum() + 1;
        newalbum.setAlbumid(newid);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Enter the name of the album :");
        textarea.setText("Enter the name of the album :");
        // String updatealbumname = scanner.nextLine();

        gettingentry = 0;
        while (gettingentry == 0) {
            System.out.println(gettingentry + " ; " + entry);
            
        }
        gettingentry = 0;
        String updatealbumname = entrystr;

        newalbum.setAlbumname(updatealbumname);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Enter the group of the album :");
        textarea.setText("Enter the group of the album :");

        gettingentry = 0;
        while (gettingentry == 0) {
            System.out.println(gettingentry + " ; " + entry);
            
        }
        gettingentry = 0;
        String updatealbumgroup = entrystr;
        newalbum.setAlbumgroup(updatealbumgroup);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Enter the length of the album :");
        textarea.setText("Enter the length of the album :");

        gettingentry = 0;
        while (gettingentry == 0) {
            System.out.println(gettingentry + " ; " + entry);
        }
        gettingentry = 0;
        int updatealbumlength = entry;
        newalbum.setAlbumlength(updatealbumlength);
        entityManager.persist(newalbum);
        String createreturn = "New album created,\nPress Enter to return to the menu";
        textarea.setText(createreturn);
        gettingentry = 0;
        while (gettingentry == 0) {
            System.out.println(gettingentry + " ; " + entry);
            // textarea.setText("Enter the ID of the album you want to view (0 to see
            // all):");
        }
        gettingentry = 0;

    }

    private static void updatealbum() {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Enter the ID of the album you want to update:");
        textarea.setText("Enter the ID of the album you want to update:");
        gettingentry = 0;
        while (gettingentry == 0) {
            System.out.println(gettingentry + " ; " + entry);
        }
        gettingentry = 0;
        Album existalbum = new Album();
        existalbum.setAlbumid(entry);
        
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Enter the name of the album you want to update:");
        textarea.setText("Enter the name of the album you want to update:");
        
        while (gettingentry == 0) {
            System.out.println(gettingentry + " ; " + entry);
        }
        gettingentry = 0;
        existalbum.setAlbumname(entrystr);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Enter the group of the album you want to update:");
        textarea.setText("Enter the group of the album you want to update:");
        
        while (gettingentry == 0) {
            System.out.println(gettingentry + " ; " + entry);
        }
        gettingentry = 0;
        existalbum.setAlbumgroup(entrystr);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Enter the length of the album you want to update:");
        textarea.setText("Enter the length of the album you want to update:");
        gettingentry = 0;
        while (gettingentry == 0) {
            System.out.println(gettingentry + " ; " + entry);
        }
        gettingentry = 0;
        
        existalbum.setAlbumlength(entry);
        entityManager.merge(existalbum);

        String updatereturn = "Album edited,\nPress Enter to return to the menu";
        textarea.setText(updatereturn);
        gettingentry = 0;
        while (gettingentry == 0) {
            System.out.println(gettingentry + " ; " + entry);
            // textarea.setText("Enter the ID of the album you want to view (0 to see
            // all):");
        }
        gettingentry = 0;
    }

    private static void viewalbum() {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Enter the ID of the album you want to view (0 to see all):");
        textarea.setText("Enter the ID of the album you want to view (0 to see all):");
        // int viewid = scanner.nextInt();
        // scanner.nextLine();

        gettingentry = 0;
        while (gettingentry == 0) {
            System.out.println(gettingentry + " ; " + entry);
            // textarea.setText("Enter the ID of the album you want to view (0 to see
            // all):");
        }
        gettingentry = 0;
        int viewid = entry;

        int i = 1;
        int nbofalbumint = (int) getnbofalbum();
        String writeswing = "";
        if (viewid <= 0) {

            while (i <= nbofalbumint) {
                Album album = entityManager.find(Album.class, i);
                String write = album.getAlbumid() + ", ";
                logger.log(Level.INFO, write);
                logger.log(Level.INFO, album.getAlbumname());
                logger.log(Level.INFO, album.getAlbumgroup());
                String write2 = album.getAlbumlength() + ".";
                logger.log(Level.INFO, write2);
                writeswing += album.getAlbumid() + ": " + album.getAlbumname() + ", " + album.getAlbumgroup() + ", "
                        + album.getAlbumlength() + ".\n";
                i++;
            }

        } else if (viewid <= nbofalbumint) {
            Album album = entityManager.find(Album.class, viewid);
            logger.log(Level.INFO, album.getAlbumname());
            logger.log(Level.INFO, album.getAlbumgroup());
            String write3 = album.getAlbumlength() + ".";
            logger.log(Level.INFO, write3);
            writeswing += album.getAlbumid() + ": " + album.getAlbumname() + ", " + album.getAlbumgroup() + ", "
                    + album.getAlbumlength() + ".\n";
        } else {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Please enter a valid ID.");
        }
        writeswing += "Press Enter to return to the menu";
        textarea.setText(writeswing);
        gettingentry = 0;
        while (gettingentry == 0) {
            System.out.println(gettingentry + " ; " + entry);
        }
        gettingentry = 0;
    }

    private static void deletealbum() {
        long nbofalbum = getnbofalbum();
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Enter the ID of the album you want to delete:");
        textarea.setText("Enter the ID of the album you want to delete:");
        gettingentry = 0;
        while (gettingentry == 0) {
            System.out.println(gettingentry + " ; " + entry);
        }
        gettingentry = 0;
        int delid=entry;
        Album reference = entityManager.getReference(Album.class, delid);
        entityManager.remove(reference);
        update();
        delid++;
        while (delid <= nbofalbum) {
            updatedeletealbum(delid);
            update();
            delid++;
        }
        int nbofalbumint = (int) nbofalbum;
        Album reference2 = entityManager.getReference(Album.class, nbofalbumint);
        entityManager.remove(reference2);
        textarea.setText("Press Enter to return to the menu.");
        gettingentry = 0;
        while (gettingentry == 0) {
            System.out.println(gettingentry + " ; " + entry);
        }
        gettingentry = 0;
    }

    private static void updatedeletealbum(int updateid) {
        Album existalbum = new Album();
        Album album = entityManager.find(Album.class, updateid);
        int newupdateid = updateid - 1;
        existalbum.setAlbumid(newupdateid);
        existalbum.setAlbumname(album.getAlbumname());
        existalbum.setAlbumgroup(album.getAlbumgroup());
        existalbum.setAlbumlength(album.getAlbumlength());
        entityManager.merge(existalbum);
    }

    private static long getnbofalbum() {

        String jpql = "select count(*) from Album";
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
        long nbofalbum = (long) query.getSingleResult();
        String write4 = "nbofalbum :" + nbofalbum;
        logger.log(Level.INFO, write4);
        return nbofalbum;
    }
}
```

Comment: can't you call a method instead of setting the variable to 1? Hence removing this ugly loop and not blocking the thread

Comment: How will this help me wait for a new value to be given ?

Comment: What context are you calling the while-loop in? If it's on the EDT thread then the listener cant be called because it's waiting for the while to finish. This is the case if while gets called before you click the button. Post the entire segment of code instead of bits.

Comment: I added the whole code, and I have no idea, I think it's due to the way the empty while will act in a different way than a while with a small body, but I can't find how to make the empty while act as I want. The while starts before the button is pressed normally

Comment: @Jason *"Post the entire segment of code instead of bits."* Tip" `[mre]` in a comment auto-expands to [mre]. Posting an MRE is more likely to gain close attention given it distills a problem down to less that a code dump of (checks)  over 340 lines. However in this case.. OP: this is an all too common problem. So common I have a comment prepared in a little app. for it:  **Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.** I suspect ..

Comment: .. that comment does not address the core of the misunderstanding in this particular case, but am unwilling to trawl through over 300 LOC trying to find what the actual problem is. Random guess: Try to understand that Java GUIs (like most GUIs in other languages), should be *event driven.*

Comment: Allright I'll look this up tomorrow, as well as a way to make the code more understandable, to find errors in a more easy way. Thanks for the help

Comment: @AndrewThomson I should have asked for a SSCCE and been less vague, but I also didn't ask for the entire application, just the entire segment that the while-loop was called in.

Comment: You can’t turn a command line program into a GUI application and still retain the same logic flow.  Instead of waiting for a valid entry, *respond* to a valid entry.